# Is the trace of the matrix exponential convex or non-convex?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, trace, positive-semidefinite, matrix-exponential

I am trying to understand whether the following expression is a convex function:
$$
f\left (\mathbf{X} \right ) =  \mathrm{tr}\left( \left ( \mathbf{\Lambda}+\alpha_0 \mathbf{\Psi}^T \left( I-e^\mathbf{{X}P} \right) \mathbf{\Psi} \right )^{-1}\right)
$$
where $\mathbf{\Lambda,P}$ both are diagonal, square and positive definite matrices, $\alpha_0$ is a constant, $\Psi$ is an orthogonal matrix that $\mathbf{\Psi^{T}\Psi}=I$. 
In fact, I am trying to solve a minimization optimization problem and the function is my objective function. To solve it with a convex-optimization tool, I have to first check its convexity.
$\mathbf{X}$ is the variable matrix we do not know in this function and it is a diagonal matrix, shown as below:
$$
\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & 0  & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & x_2 &  & 0\\ 
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and 
$$
e^\mathbf{XP} = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{x_1 p_1} & 0  & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & e^{x_2 p_2} &  & 0\\ 
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & e^{x_n p_n}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

To show the convexity of the function $f$, the common way is to define a new function $g\left ( t \right )=f\left ( \mathbf{X}+t\mathbf{V} \right )$ and try to get the twice derivatives $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\partial^2 g\left ( t \right ) }{\partial t^2}$ greater or equal to zero. However, it is too complicated for me to solve it. It is very appreciate that someone can help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: How is convexity defined for matrix-valued functions?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the trace makes it scalar valued

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo that being said, convexity would typically be defined relative to the Loewner ordering

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sure, but please re-read the title.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Ah, I assumed that OP just phrased the question incorrectly there and that the title should have been "is a *function with a variable matrix* in exponent a convex or non-convex function"

Comment: @gary Is $\mathbf \Psi$ a square matrix?

Comment: Is inversion taken before (as I think) or after trace operator ?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Sorry for an inexact title. Would it be better to change the title to "Is the function convex on the subspace of diagonal matrices?"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, $\mathbf{\Psi}$ is a square matrix.

Comment: @JeanMarie Right, the inversion operator is taken before trace. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: I proposed a new title. It can be improved further.